# ListId GUID substitution in CAML in Share Point 2010 (and other subsitutions)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml, substitution

There's a new syntax element in SP 2010's feature definitions **{$ListId:Lists/ListName}**. Apparently it should replace it with the GUID of the list on traget site. This solves a problem where you don't know the GUID before you create the list and have to use a feature receiver to define elements which need the GUID.

Is there other such substitutions? Is there a list of them available?

Thanks!